# Mongoose updateMany documents containing specific Array element

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've got a `Mongoose` schema set up as follows:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const TodoSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  id: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  todos: {
    type: Array,
    required: true,
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now(),
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('todo', TodoSchema, 'todos');
```

Each of the elements in the `todos` Array is an Object and has the following format (example):

```json
{
  id: 1,
  todo: "Do the dishes."
  category: "Kitchen"
}
```

There are multiple documents in my `Todo` collection and they all contain the same list of Todos. If I wanted to update a specific Todo across ALL documents, I figure I need to use `updateMany`. I'm using the following in my Todo Update route to update all instances of a Todo:

```js
const { todo } = req.body; // todo.todo contains "Clean the dishes." as an update

Todo.updateMany(
  {
    todos: { $elemMatch: { id: todo.id } },
  },
  { $set: { todo: todo } }
);
```

I'm assigning the result of the above route code to a variable and console logging the result which comes back with:

`{ ok: 0, n: 0, nModified: 0 }`

What am I doing wrong? The passed `todo` id matches the id of a Todo in each of the `Todos` arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, for your object array, is recommendable create a schema too:

```js
const subSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    id: Number,
    todo: String,
    category: String
})
const MongooseModel = new mongoose.Schema({
    id: String,
    todos: [subSchema],
    date: Date
})
```

So now, your array object is defined.

And, the query question is something like that:

```
db.collection.update({
  "todos.id": todo.id
},
{
  "$set": {
    "todos.$": {newTodo}
  }
},
{
  "multi": true
})
```

First, you look for all elements that match your criteria; that is: `todos.id = todo.id`, then you use `$` operator to set all element that match the criteria with your object.
The last line `multi` is to updated all element that match.

Example playground [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VO-6r3V55tu)

Using moongoose, `multi` attribute is not neccessary because is set `true` by default using `updateMany()`.

So moongose query should be something like that.

```js
var update = await model.updateMany(
    {
        "todos.id": 1
    },
    {
    "$set": {
        "todos.$": {
            "id": 20,
            "todo": "newTodo",
            "category": "newCategory"
        }
    }
})
```

And for this example data the result is

```
{ n: 3, nModified: 3, ok: 1 }
```